# can not login when i add login with mobile functionality php

Tags: php, database, authentication

i have a login form in which user can login through mobile number or email or username now when i login through mobile number it works fine but when i login through username or email it says invalid how to make it works and when i remove the query for mobile login it works fine with username and email
this is my php code

```
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,trim($_POST['email'])); 
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,md5(trim($_POST['password'])));
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$email' or email = '$email' or mobile='$email')   AND password='$password' ";
$fire = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die(mysqli_error($con));
 if ($fire) {
if (mysqli_num_rows($fire) == 1) {


  $_SESSION['is_login'] = 'true';
  $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

  header("Location: dashboard");

}
```

how to solve this problem what am i doing wrong please help me and i wana do it with php only no javascript and ajax

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use **[PHP's built-in functions](//php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the password_hash() **[compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)**. Make sure you **[don't escape passwords](//stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: @JohnConde i am using md5 to secure passwords but please tell me the solution to my problem

Comment: `md5()` is obsolete for hashing passwords and should *not be used*. PHP provides [password_hash()](//php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](//php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), please use them. And here are some [good ideas about passwords](//www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet). If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: the RDBMS and connection api are unknown. Enable error reporting and check for errors on the query.

Comment: @JohnConde okay ill take a look at that but do u have any solution to my problem??

Comment: Code should work, albeit unsecurely.

Comment: Please share the error, _it says invalid_ aren't very useful for us

Comment: Do you really mean to try and match `username` , `email` and `mobile` against the `$email` ? Looks like a TYPO to me!

Comment: Seems you posted this already https://stackoverflow.com/q/52738973/1415724 and is still "in limbo".

Comment: @RiggsFolly they are `$password       = md5($password);`.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Opps missed it :)

Comment: database is not showing any error it is just not matching the correct email and password

Comment: Did you see [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740808/can-not-login-when-i-add-login-with-mobile-functionality-php?noredirect=1#comment92406459_52740808) about trying to match everything to `$email`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i have only 1 field for all username ,email and mobile number so that user can login with either one of them and that field is stored in one variable $email

Answer (score -1):

actually i had email and username field in varchar but number field in big int i changed number field in varchar it solved the problem